# Other textfield required jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that looks like this:[image]

I am able to easily validate the name field, email field, and checkbox group, but I would like the checkbox group to fail if the other checkbox is checked and the additional field is not filled out.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfLmana8/**

This is my JS (not working for the checkbox):

```
$('#contact').validate({
    rules: {
      other: {
        required: {
          depends: function(element) {
            return $(".contact_more_info_other_chk").is(":checked");
          }
        }
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      if (element.name == 'name') {
        $('.contact_name').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      } else if (element.name == 'email') {
        $('.contact_email').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      } else if (element.name == 'more_info[]' ) {
        $('.contact_more_info').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      } else if (element.name == 'other') {
        $('.contact_more_info').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        $('.contact_more_info_other_txt').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      }
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      if (element.name == 'name') {
        $('.contact_name').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
      } else if (element.name == 'email') {
        $('.contact_email').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
      } else if (element.name == 'more_info[]') {
        $('.contact_more_info').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
      } else if (element.name == 'other') {
        $('.contact_more_info').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
        $('.contact_more_info_other_txt').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
      }
    },
  });
})
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="contact">
 <div class="contact_name">
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
   <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle form-feedback"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle form-feedback"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="contact_email">
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
   <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle form-feedback"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle form-feedback"></i>
 </div>
 <div>
   <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company">
 </div>
 <div>
   <input type="text" name="fav_brand" placeholder="Favorite Brand">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="contact_more_info">
 <h3>What keeps you up at night?</h3>
 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle form-feedback"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-check-circle form-feedback"></i>
 <div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]" required> Lead gen / gain interest
   </label>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]"> Customer dev / relationship growth
   </label>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]"> Lead nurture / inform to conversion
   </label>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]"> Retention / minimize attention
   </label>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]"> Onboarding / experience management
   </label>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]"> Winback / recoupe lost revenue
   </label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
     <input type="checkbox" name="more_info[]" class="contact_more_info_other_chk"> Other <input class="other" type="text" name="other" class="contact_more_info_other_txt">
 </div>
</div>
 <div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You absolutely would not need to add/remove the classes to each and every individual field within `highlight` and `unhighlight`... that defeats the whole purpose of having the `element` keyword.  Simply replace it all with one line within `highlight` , `$(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass)` and the complementary line within `unhighlight`.

Comment: It's kinda important to show us the relevant HTML.

Comment: @Sparky I'm adding the class to another element on the page, hence why I'm adding/removing this way (please let me know if this is still unnecessary). HTML has been added.

Comment: In that case, there are many jQuery DOM traversal methods you could use to find the element relative to each input. It should be more generic... that's the beauty of jQuery.  Something like... `$(element).next('someclass').siblings('label')`,

Comment: Also, you should use `return false` within `errorPlacement` rather than an empty function.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `})` after `.validate()`.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your `depends` code... working for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/vz3t35fg/

Comment: @Sparky I will make those changes. Thank you! The `depends` code works. The issue I'm having is that if 'Other' is checked, and the text field is empty, my error class for the text field is applied correctly, but my checkbox group error class isn't. Refer to this image: http://i.imgur.com/KL8VZeL.png

Comment: @Sparky Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfLmana8/

Comment: I think I finally get it.  You want the checkbox group to fail validation if the box is blank when the "other" checkbox is checked.  You'll probably have to write a custom method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need a custom method for the checkbox group.  This sees if the last checkbox is checked and fails if the text box is left blank.

```
$.validator.addMethod('otherbox', function(value, element, params) {
    if ($(".contact_more_info_other_chk").is(':checked')) {
        return ($('[name="other"]').is(':filled')) ? true : false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

within the `rules` object...

```
    rules: {
        other: {
            required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $(".contact_more_info_other_chk").is(":checked");
                }
            }
        },
        'more_info[]': {
            required: true,
            otherbox: true
        }
    }
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/L76fvhym/**

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thanks for all your help!!